# Array_diff не хочет работать правильно

Tags: diff, массивы, php

Дня доброго. Сломал себе уже голову... Сравниваю 2 массива

```
$a = Array
(
    'login' => 'kerryTy',
    'timezone' => '4.00',
    'lang' => 'russian',
    'gender' => '2',
    'birthday' => '1990-01-01',
    'cat_send' => '304',
    'from' => 'Russian',
    'interests' => 'котики)))',
    'signature' => 'test me)',
    'join' => '1'
);
$b = Array
(
    'login' => 'TheSuperMAn))',
    'timezone' => '4.00',
    'lang' => 'russian',
    'gender' => '1',
    'birthday' => '1989-03-14',
    'cat_send' => '304',
    'from' => 'Russian Федерация',
    'interests' => 'Вообще нету',
    'signature' => 'oooooololo',
    'join' => '1'
);
$resoult =  array_diff($b, $a);
```

и получаю результат

```
Array
(
    [login] => TheSuperMAn))
    [birthday] => 1989-03-14
    [from] => Russian Федерация
    [interests] => Вообще нету
    [signature] => oooooololo
)
```

что тут не правильно? а то что функция потеряла параметр

```
gender
```

результат должен был быть таким

```
Array
(
    [login] => TheSuperMAn))
    [gender] => 1
    [birthday] => 1989-03-14
    [from] => Russian Федерация
    [interests] => Вообще нету
    [signature] => oooooololo
)
```

так почему так получается? мне кажется оба значения определяются как **TRUE** и по этому не сравниваются. Подскажите как решить проблему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, что вам надо использовать функцию [array_diff_assoc()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-diff-assoc.php)

```
$resoult =  array_diff_assoc($b, $a);
// результат:
Array
(
    [login] => TheSuperMAn))
    [gender] => 1
    [birthday] => 1989-03-14
    [from] => Russian Федерация
    [interests] => Вообще нету
    [signature] => oooooololo
)
```